# read excel data line by line with c# .net

Tags: c#, .net

Does anyone know how can I read an excel file line by line in c#.

I found this code which will return the data from excel and display a grindview in c#. However, I just was wandering how to possibly read the data line by line on the server side instead?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;    
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;

namespace site
{
    public partial class pgTest : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connString = "";
            string strFileType = Path.GetExtension(fileuploadExcel.FileName).ToLower();
            string path = fileuploadExcel.PostedFile.FileName;
            //Connection String to Excel Workbook
            if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xls")
            {
                connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
            }
            else if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xlsx")
            {
                connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
            }

            string query = "SELECT [username],[age],[phone] FROM [Sheet1$]";
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            grvExcelData.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            grvExcelData.DataBind();
            da.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: This code will do; just don't bind the data into a "grvExcelData" (I guess that has to do something with the Grid view). Or even better; you could use the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel APIs

Comment: this code provide what you want in the dataset, isn't it?

Comment: I believe he just want's to check on how to read excel files line by line and not reading the whole excel file and loading its value to the grid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use `OleDbDataReader` as below

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);

    connection.Open();
    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var val1= reader[0].ToString();
    }
    reader.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Since Excel works with ranges you should first get the range of cells you would want to read. After that you can now browse through them using a for loop. You can see an example below:

```
    Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\myexcel.xlsx");
    Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
    Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

    int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
    int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

    for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString());
        }
    }
```

A more detailed explanation on this code block can be found [here](http://dontbreakthebuild.com/2011/01/30/excel-and-c-interop-with-net-4-how-to-read-data-from-excel/).

Comment: Lem, can you please update the link you have provided...its not working anymore...Thank you

Comment: Link is currently a 404.

Answer (score 1):

You must try this

```
        string connectionString = "";
        string strFileType = "Type";
        string path = @"C:\Users\UserName\Downloads\";
        string filename = "filename.xls";
        if (fielname.Contains(.xls))
        {
            connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + filename + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
        }
        else if (fielname.Contains(.xlsx)
        {
            connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + filename + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
        }


        string query = "SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]";
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);

            connection.Open();
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            var lines = new List<string>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var fieldCount = reader.FieldCount;

                var fieldIncrementor = 1;
                var fields = new List<string>();
                while (fieldCount >= fieldIncrementor)
                {
                    fields.Add(reader[fieldIncrementor - 1].ToString());
                    fieldIncrementor++;
                }

                lines.Add(string.Join("\t", fields));
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution with OleDbConnection but it didn't work because I didn't have something installed. Then I found this solution here and it worked like a charm:

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/801032/Csharp-How-To-Read-xlsx-Excel-File-With-Lines-of

There you can download a small file Excel.dll, add it to your project and browse the excel files cell by cell.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to convert data table to enumerable of an object is using Json methods.

Per example, with simple method, using only dotnet libraries, you can convert data table to list of especific objects.

```cs
        using System.Data;
    
        private static IEnumerable<T> ConvertDataTable<T>(DataTable dataTable)
        {
            if (dataTable is null ||
                !dataTable.AsEnumerable().Any())
            {
                return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
            }
    
            var data = dataTable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                .Select(row => dataTable.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>()
                    .ToDictionary(col => col.ColumnName, c => row[c]));
            
            var jsonTextObject = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
    
            return System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<T>>(jsonTextObject)
                ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
        }
```