# Wants to check if the last cell of the row is null or contains some data in excel sheet, c#

Tags: c#, excel

I have a scenario in which I need to check the last cell of a/any row in an excel sheet. I can find lots of results on internet describing how to get the last row and column, but my requirement is to get the data on the last cell in a/any row using c#.

```
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        Excel.Range range;

        string[] str = null;xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        //Opening Excel file
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(here workbook open code is written);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        //Gives the used cells in the sheet
        range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;int lastRow1 = range.Rows.Count;
```

After reaching at the last row. How to know the last cell in this row.
I hope it is more clear now. If not please ask.

Comment: "but my requirement is" making requirements is not asking ...

Comment: If you have the last cell in a row of data, you can get the value using that reference. I don't understand what you're asking or why you are having trouble with it when you have got as far as you say you have. Post some code.

Comment: My excel sheet will expand according to user searching filter criteria. So at run time it will not known that which will be the last cell and in which row. That's why I could not hard code it. Take a look at my code:

Comment: Fetching data from the last cell should be the same as fetching it from the first cell or any other cell. The only variation is in the coordinates of the cell you request. So get the coordinates of the cell you want, and then fetch the data as you would from any other cell. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Using C# you can get full access to Excel Object model.

as an example take a look here:

[read excel data line by line with c# .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16160676/read-excel-data-line-by-line-with-c-sharp-net)

My big tip to you is that if you use Macro Recorder in Excel then you can use Almost the exact same generated code in C#!